# Shifting info when window open

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to replace variables from one window to another to make the object. This is my public class:

```
public class Food
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Food(string name, string description, int price)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
    }
}
```

This is my Main Window code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow();
        newWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And this is my New Window code:

```
public partial class NewWindow : Window
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    Food _food;       
    public NewWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string name = mainWindow.comboMenu.Text;
        string description = mainWindow.textDescription.Text;
        int price = int.Parse(mainWindow.textPrice.Text);

        _food = new Food(name, description, price);
    }
}
```

The problem is the name, description and price in Main Window is changing due to user choice clicking the interface. But the New Window take the info which appears in Main Window when programm start working and dont mind about user choice. So i need to set variables in New Window when its opening. Or when Next button click event in Main Window called from New Window. Please advice the simpler way to make it. The main idea is to withdraw the information from Main Window to New Window when first is closed and new is opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the instance of Food type in main window and pass it to newwindow
Something like this.
In case a reference to main window is required then even that can be passed in the constructor too.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = comboMenu.Text;
        string description = textDescription.Text;
        int price = int.Parse(textPrice.Text);

        NewWindow newWindow = new NewWindow(new Food(name, description, price));
        newWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}

public partial class NewWindow : Window
{
    //MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    Food _food;       
    public NewWindow(Food food)
        {
        _food = food;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, thats working as i want. @neelesh bodgal